# Auto populate a table from a json file

Tags: php, json, html

I have a basic table, that reads data from a json file to fill the rows  This fill is updated by a 3rd party application, and I'd need to add new rows automatically, without the viewer having to refresh the page. Mostly I'm looking for tutorials or some such on how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance for any advice!

```
$strJsonFileContents = file_get_contents("./includes/dispatch.json");
$mdt = json_decode($strJsonFileContents, true);
?>
<div id="callboard">
    <div align="center">
            Call ID: <input type="text" id="AlertId" class="mdt" size="10" readonly  />
            Type: <input type="text" id="AlertType" class="mdt" size="10" readonly  />
            Location: <input type="text" id="AlertLocation" class="mdt" size="25" readonly  />
            Status: <input type="text" id="AlertStatus" class="mdt" size="10" readonly  />
            Units: <input type="text" id="AlertUnits" class="mdt" size="20" readonly  /><hr><span id='ct' ></span><hr>
    </div>
<hr>
    <h3>Active Calls</h3>
    <table id="mdt-table">
    <tr onclick="javascript:showRow(this);">
    <th>Call ID</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Caller</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Details</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th colspan="2">Units</th>
    <th>Other Info</th></tr>
    <?php
    $arrlength = count($mdt);
    for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)
            {
            if ($mdt[$x][AlertType]=='10-13')
                    {
                    echo "<tr class=\"blinking\" onclick=\"javascript:showRow(this);\">";
                    }
            else { echo "<tr onclick=\"javascript:showRow(this);\">";
                    }
            echo "<td name=\"AlertId\">". $mdt[$x][AlertID]; echo "</td>";
            echo "<td name=\"AlertType\">". $mdt[$x][AlertType]; echo "</td>";
            echo "<td name=\"AlertCaller\">". $mdt[$x][AlertCaller]; echo "</td>";
            echo "<td name=\"AlertLocation\">". $mdt[$x][AlertLocation]; echo "</td>";
            echo "<td name=\"AlertMessage\">". $mdt[$x][AlertMessage]; echo "</td>";
            echo "<td name=\"AlertStatus\">". $mdt[$x][AlertStatus]; echo "</td>";
            echo "<td name=\"AlertUnits\" colspan=\"2\">". $mdt[$x][AlertUnits]; echo "</td>";
            echo "<td name=\"AlertOther\">". $mdt[$x][AlertOther]; echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
?>
    </table>
```

Comment: anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You have to add javascript (ajax) code to your page and get data and update table with it.

Answer (score 0):

When you grab the JSON data, specifically the string, you can use the PHP function `json_decode($raw_json_string)` that will return an associative array (  if js object ) or just a regular array ( js array )

if you want to fetch JSON data for javascript, you can use the php function

`json_encode($array);` that will return a string ready to use in Javascript as an object variable.

so if you want to use a JSON object in PHP....

php:

`

```
$raw_json_string = {data: 2, data2:"hello world", data3:[1,2,3,4],};
$array = json_decode($raw_json_string);

$array['data'] == 2; // true

$array['data2'] == "hello world"; // true 

$array['data3'] == [1,2,3,4]; // true`
```

then you can use this array and loop through it to create your HTML table rows.

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! I'm already doing that. My question is, when the remote source adds a new entry in the json file, the html(php) table will auto update with the new row without any user assistance.

Comment: ok. whatever HTML you print with `php` when the page loads, thats all `php` can do for you since it's server side - basically PHP prints once. You will need to incorporate Javascript into the page to dynamically add the rows from data fetched with AJAX. Jquery will allow you to append an element to the table and make it easier to do this instead of vanilla javascript.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Comment: yeah I get that part of it.  Appreciate the feedback on jquery/ajax. I'll dig into it.